# Jquery Datatable TableTools open pdf option

Tags: jquery, datatables, tabletools

How can i save the pdf/excel file (in any default location) instead of prompting user through save as dailog box as current tabletool does.

Comment: can't save to local file with javascript. If you mean at server would need to send all the table data via ajax and process to file typ you want there

Comment: I like to avoid doing a unnecessary server response,what i found in ZeroClipboardpdf.as it is using filerefrence.save() method to save a file,but can i anyway stop the browser to prompt a save as dailog box and save in local drive?...Thanks for your answer charlietfl

Comment: doubt it... research clipboard to file using flash maybe

Comment: Things are getting little doggy now for me,if i have to digg to server  side java to write out the table content,i will loose all the essence of tabeltools...any suggestion?